# Extract nested .msg attachment using javamail api

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

I've outlook email data in the firm of `EML`  files. There are various levels of nesting of attachments.

Is there a generic way to extract the attached `.msg` and its attachments recursively?

A full piece of code or relevant code snippet would be much more helpful than plain approach.

Comment: The JavaMail sample program [msgshow.java](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java) should help.

Comment: So is it an EML file or an MSG file?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a library called [msgparser](http://auxilii.com/msgparser/Page.php?id=100).

They list some very basic usage [examples](http://auxilii.com/msgparser/Page.php?id=18000):

```
MsgParser msgp = new MsgParser();
Message msg = msgp.parseMsg("mail.msg");

String fromEmail = msg.getFromEmail();
String fromName = msg.getFromName();
String subject = msg.getSubject();

List<Attachment> atts = msg.getAttachments();
for (Attachment att : atts) {
  // do something with attachment
}
```

Comment: the function List<Attachment> atts = msg.getAttachments();
for (Attachment att : atts) {
  // do something with attachment
}
is returning file name like abc.pdf, now how can I get this abc.pdf or how can I open it, its returning only attachment name